# Loading page fragments using $.post in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am fetching 2 div's from a page using $.post jQuery AJAX request.  Now the data that comes after the execution is from a POST request and is something like this...

```
//data.php
<div id="alpha">alpha</div><div id="beta">beta</div>
```

Now if i want to load the data of just the div with id 'alpha' into a div with id 'container' in the present page and if the data came by a GET request my life would be easier...

```
$("#container").load('data.php #alpha');
```

would solve the problem.

I want to do similar filtering on success function using $.post function in jQuery so i can load the appropriate div's at the appropriate page in the current page.  How can i achieve this?

```
$.post('data.php',null,function(data){
//what to do here?
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response is exactly as you describe and does not have a root element.

```
$.post("some url", {},
  function(data) {
    var $d = $("<div/>").append(data);
    $('body').append($d.find("#alpha"));
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/MndkH/)**

Comment: Works like a charm but can you explain why we had to append data first to a '<div/>' tag?

Comment: @LoneWOLFs, the reason is because they response is treated as an array of two jQuery objects `$(data).length = 2` Appending it to a div allows you to find the `id` from the parent correctly.  Issuing a `find()` from `$(data)` fails since both items have no children.  To make it work without `$("<div/>")` you can use `.filter()` like `$(data).filter("#alpha");` which will reduce the set to the correct  matched selector.

Comment: Awesome, cleared the doubts pretty well.  Thanks a trillion for replying.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post('data.php',
       function(data){
    $("#container").html($(data).find('#alpha'));

});
```

assuming you are replacing the entirety of container. if you're appending it then...

```
$.post('data.php',
       function(data){
    $("#container").append($(data).find('#alpha'));

});
```

Comment: FatherStorm data contains 2 div's I need to seperate them out.

Comment: FatherStorm the above code does not work.  I don't think $(data) is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').append($(data).find('#alpha'));
```